# HTML5 applicationCache in local development

Tags: caching, html

I'm experimenting with application cache based on this example:
http://html5demos.com/html5demo.manifest

This example works fine in ff, but when I create analogous site (almost identical) I get only status "UNCACHED (numeric value 0) -- The ApplicationCache object's cache host is not associated with an application cache at this time."

I work on xampp and I've set correct mime-type. When the page is loading ff "is asking to store data on your computer for offline use" and when I show Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Network -> Offline data there is localhost but with 0B size.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've solved it out. The problem is in Apache. I've added correct mime-type in /conf/mime.types but apparently it is not enough. I've also added entry in .htacces and then eveyrthing started working.

Answer (score 0):

It says right there on the page http://html5demos.com/ that Firefox is still buggy:

> offline application using the manifest FF 3.6 is still buggy - doesn't request manifest after initial load

Maybe try a WebKit browser?

Comment: As I said: this example works on page that I provided link. The problem is when I try to copy code.